# While installing Win 10, used diskpart, I ran clean command by mistake on the whole disk, so it becomes a single 465 GB partition

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, data-recovery, diskpart

While installing Windows 10, used diskpart to format one of my drive, I ran clean command by mistake on the whole disk, so it becomes a single 465 GB partition. Previously, it contained four partitions. I did't install any OS and just turned laptop off.  How can I recover them with the data intact?

## Should i remove hard and attached it with some other laptop for recovery?

Answer (score -1):

yes, you should remove it and plug it on another laptop for recovery (if you want to try free/paid recovery tools like [RECUVA](https://www.ccleaner.com/recuva) or simmilar solutions), however chances are very low to get back all those data without residual corruption. better idea is to visit some recovery center and seek help there. it may be costy but they have more advanced tools. however even then, there is 50% chance that your data are lost beyond full scale restoration. ofc all depends of money...